# Asus motherboard in the $50-$150 range

Tags: gaming, motherboard

What motherboard from the Asus z170 chipset line offers the most set of features? I did some research and it looks like the z170-a is the one but I could be wrong. I'd like to have a motherboard that offers the most features even if I won't necessarily need them. I just like to have the most possible options.

Here are a few things I would hope to include but don't let that affect your answer:

- USB 3.1, type a and c
- Possibility to do SLI in the future

Some things that I plan to do with the system are:

- Everyday usage
- Gaming
- Web development and running WAMP server for development
- Media server using Plex
- Photoshop

I already plan on buying a GTX 1070 graphics card so I can play games on the highest graphics settings possible.

Comment: This is quite broad of a request.  What are you looking for in the board?  What will you be using the system for?

Comment: @NZKshatriya I added some info about what I plan to do with the system. I hope they can make my request more answerable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with this one:  [ASUS Z170-E](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813132691&ignorebbr=1)

These points jump out, at least at me:

DDR4 memory overclocked to 3466MHz(max compatible speed) 
Onboard USB 3.1 Gen 2 for 10Gbit/s data transfer speeds
Lightning-fast M.2 with PCIe 3.0 x4 interface